# Why a command like combnk(1:3,2) does not work in Matlab 2011a?

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know why one can't use the command

```
combnk(1:3,2)
```

in Matlab 2011a, or is there any way to make this built-in function working? The error message I got is

```
???Undefined function or method 'combnk' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Comment: Do you have the statistics toolbox? You need it for `combnk`.

Comment: If you don't have the statistics toolbox, you can use `nchoosek` instead, e.g. `nchoosek(1:3, 2)`

Answer (score 6):

The two most common reasons for `Undefined function or method`-errors are (1) typos, and (2) lack of the appropriate toolbox.

If you're sure you didn't make any spelling mistake, try `ver` on the command line to check which toolboxes you have installed. If the statistics toolbox is missing, there won't be `combnk` on the path.

*additional tip by Colin T Bowers*

If `ver` indicates you do have the statistics toolbox, then try `which combnk`. If this returns `combnk not found`, then you may need to refresh your path, with something like `restoredefaultpath` then `savepath`

Comment: Just a small addition to this excellent answer: If `ver` indicates you do have the statistics toolbox, then try `which combnk`. If this returns `combnk not found`, then you may need to refresh your path, with something like `restoredefaultpath` then `savepath`.